# Returned 'undefined' when trying to access form-data file on express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, form-data

For this I'm using express.js, react, with the help of form-data.

No matter what I try, when I send a file from the frontend to the server, the server always says it's undefined.

In react, the code is as follows:

```
onSubmit = () => {
        const url = '../api/products/file';
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.state.file)
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }
        console.log(formData);
        axios.post(url, formData, config)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.statusText)
        })
    }
```

I know the computer has the file because this.state.file returns all the relevant info on the file.
For reference, in the console.log(formData) line, I receive this in the console.
[image: Console view of console.log(formData)]

In express, the code is as follows:

```
router.post('/file', (req,res) => {
    console.log("FILE");
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.body);
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            return res.status(500).json(err)
        } else if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err)
        }
    return res.status(200).send(req.file)
    })
});
```

My problem here is that my `req.file` returns 'undefined' whereas my `req.body` returns {} which indicates that the file isn't even making its way to the server. I'm thinking that either the file isn't going to the form-data properly through appending or it's somehow getting lost on the way to the server which I think is highly unlikely. I've looked over every line of the request of Axios and there's no details on the files within.

Comment: Did you use body-parser?

Comment: Actually `console.log(formData)` tells you nothing about the file being loaded or not. FormData is just a JS object which you have printed to the console. To make sure that file is there you have to at least `console.log(this.state.file)` and `console.log(formData.get('file')` and check what is there

Comment: @Rostyslav Thank you I didn't know about this! I did formData.get('file') and it appears so it's definitely being loaded.